# Emberjs - actions get triggered 3 times on a single click

Tags: ember.js

In my app using Emberjs, every action gets triggered 3 times on a single click.

For example with the following template and view:

Template:

```
<button {{action "removeFoo"}}>remove</button>
```

View with click handler:

```
listsView = Ember.View.create({
  templateName: 'lists',

  removeFoo: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(new Date().valueOf());
  }
})
```

I get the following 3 outputs in the console:

```
1333634360209
1333634360215
1333634360217
```

Does anybody know what's causing this or what's the best approach to debug the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem was, that the Ember app was part of a Rails application which had two other Ember apps already. Those Ember apps didn't have a `rootElement` specified. Adding a `rootElement` for every Ember app fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's being called multiple times, but are you intentionally overriding `Ember.View#remove`? If so you'll probably want to call `this._super()` so that it destroys the element etc...

Here's the definition of it in the source:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L770

If that wasn't your intention, you might want to call your action something else and see if resolves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, my actions are actually named differently. I changed the example. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ah no problem, can you replicate it over at jsfiddle.net? As per @pangratz, it seems to work fine for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Ember.js version **0.9.6** works fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/BxccU/